# Validating specific hidden input field in html for not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, hidden

I have a html form with an input field to add comma separated tags. I have handled it in such a way that there is main input which takes a string and on entering comma a tag is created and added to a hidden input. Now I want to validate whether the hidden input which is the actual input field with tags is empty on form submit and show message accordingly.

```
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"  >Tags</label>
        <div class="controls">

            <div class="tags-input" id = "tags" name="tags"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Both the main input and hidden input fields are created dynamically on body load inside div with class tags-input using below function

```
function processTag() {
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tags-input'), function (el) {
    let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input'),
        mainInput = document.createElement('input'),
        tags = [];

    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', el.id);
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('id', el.id);
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('required', '');
}
```

I have tried all the approaches to solve the problem. required="required" does not work with hidden input field. Validating the form using class name like below also does not work

$("#createForm").validate({ 
    ignore: ":hidden:not(.do_not_ignore)"
});

Can someone help me in suggesting a solution for this ?

Comment: I think we might be able to help you if you can post a working example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Required is a reflected atribute. Correct approach is element.required = true. And if you want to use the document.getElementsByClassName you should use his index[].

Comment: Tried hiddenInput.setAttribute('required', 'true'); but not working

Comment: hiddenInput.required = true;